# javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Failed to access the WSDL

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl

```
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Failed to access the WSDL at: https://xxxx.com/saw.dll?wsdl. It failed with: 
    sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target.
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Failed to access the WSDL at: https://xxxxxxx.com/saw.dll?wsdl. It failed with: 
    sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target.
    at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.tryWithMex(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:249)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:230)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:193)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:162)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1917)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:301)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:295)
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:145)
```

I faced this exception when i try to call soap web service method. how can i solve this problem ?

Comment: I try to connect webService using webService Client . parsing WSDL has done ,but i want to use webService Methods , i got some error like this

Comment: did you ever find a solution for this? i am also facing the same issue.

Comment: i solved it that using FakeX509TrustManager.java, im adding class , you just call allowAllSSL() method before sending information to webService

Comment: You just saved my day (week) THANK YOU !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this exception and here is the class which helps me figure the problem out. if you face this error when you call webservice method then please call allowSSL() method then call your ws call method.

```
import java.security.KeyManagementException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSession;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;

public class FakeX509TrustManager implements X509TrustManager {

private TrustManager[] trustManagers;
private final X509Certificate[] _AcceptedIssuers = new X509Certificate[]{};

@Override
public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
}

@Override
public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
}

public boolean isClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain) {
    return true;
}

public boolean isServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain) {
    return true;
}

@Override
public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
    return _AcceptedIssuers;
}

public void allowAllSSL() throws KeyManagementException {
    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
        @Override
        public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
            return true;
        }
    });
    SSLContext context = null;
    if (trustManagers == null) {
        trustManagers = new TrustManager[]{new FakeX509TrustManager()};
    }
    try {
        context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        context.init(null, trustManagers, new SecureRandom());
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(context.getSocketFactory());
}

}
```